# How to make TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE column with Ruby Sequel?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, timezone, sequel-gem

I am learning Ruby and Sequel, and trying to make some table.

I want to save my time value as in UTC in PostgreSQL database. So I made a table with

```
db.create_table :TestTable1 do
    Timestamp   :field1
end
```

but I got

```
field1 | timestamp without time zone |           | plain    |
```

I want my value in database to have strict basis. So I want to force everything in UTC. I think there should be a way to make `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When creating the table, you can specify specific types:

```
db.create_table :TestTable1 do
  column :field1, 'timestamp with time zone'
end
```

You probably want to use `Sequel.default_timezone = :utc` as well, but that doesn't affect how times are actually stored in the database.

Comment: If I don't do `Sequel.default_timezone = :utc`, will Sequel perform UTC(in DB) <-> local(in Ruby) conversion? If it handles it automatically, it would be also nice.

Comment: It may do that, it may not.  If you want to enforce that behavior `Sequel.database_timezone = :utc` and `Sequel.application_timezone = :local`.